# how to extract graph in a hand written word image

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

I have taken one hand written word image as input for my program, I want to resize that image into 100x100 after resizing am skeletonised that image and i divide that image into equal segments of 10x10 in that segment i want to find the center of mass for foreground pixels in each segments. in my program i am finding the center of mass for foreground pixel. in my algorithm which am trying to implement they told that use that center of mass as a node add it into resulting graph and add the Add edges based on edge extraction like Minimal Spanning
Tree (MST).my question is i know the center of mass of foreground pixels im my code values of x and y coordinates stored in CXX and CYY matrix using plot(CXX,CYY,'g*'); am plotting on image. but i do not know how to use that center of mass as a node add it into resulting graph and how to add edges using MST.

this is my output image:
[image: this is my output image]

I want to use that plotted points as a node to resulting graph, after adding that points as a node i want add the edges based on Minimum Spanning Tree. please help me to how can i add those plotted point as nodes to resulting graph and how can i add edges to those nodes using minimum spanning tree.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
X=imread('math1.jpg');
imfinfo('math1.jpg')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
%figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
I = im2bw(b,th);

% w = 5;
% h = 5;
% c=si/w;
% r=sj/h;
kl=bwmorph(~I,'thin',inf);
%figure,imshow(kl)

R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
%grid size 
t1=5;
D=100;
 I=1;
U1=t1;
J=1;
U2=t1;
E=1;
t2=D/t1;
%Z=1;
for i=1:t2
    for j=1:t2
 B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
 [x,y]=find(B==1);
 CX=mean(x);
 CY=mean(y);
 CXXX(E)=CX;
 CYYY(E)=CY;
 CXX(i,j)=CX;
 CYY(i,j)=CY;

 T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
    J=J+t1;
  U2=U2+t1;
E=E+1;
 clear B x y 

    end

I=I+t1;
U1=U1+t1;
J=1;
  U2=t1;

end
%plot and grid
figure,imshow(R)
hold on
M = size(R,1);
N = size(R,2);

a=t1; 
b=t1;
for k = 1:a:M
    x = [1 N]; 
   y = [k k]; 
   plot(x,y,'Color','white');
   set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end
for k = 1:b:N 
    x = [k k]; 
    y = [1 M];
    plot(x,y,'Color','white');
    set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end

plot(CYY,CXX,'c*')
```

this is my input image please try to run this code.

my input image 
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJkwq.jpg)

Comment: Thats some nice wizardry you got going on there to display the matrix in a nice format. :)

Comment: Sir. Am not getting you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question as I don't use matlab. I just wanted to comment on your wonderful formatting of the matrix.

Comment: It's OK thank you.

Comment: Sir, In my hand written 100x100 word image I skeletonised that image and divide into 10x10 equal segments, in each segment I find the foreground pixels and find its centre of mass, i calculated centre of  mass using centre of mass formula. Values of x stored in CX matrix and values of y stored in CY matrix. If the use 'plot(CX,CY,'g*'); ' I get the centre of mass of foreground pixel in each segment, if I consider that centre of mass as node. I want to add edges to that nodes,

Comment: Is there any methods to create adjacency matrix using this coordinate values

Comment: In my previous questions how to add the edges using minimum spanning tree I posted my code over there in my code there is a variable called CXX and CYY these values are stored. Please try to run that code you will come to know please sir.

Comment: Anybody there please guide me